# making multiple links visible javascript

Tags: javascript

Can multiple links get visible at a time? I mean in my following code when I enter `project` in the text field and press submit button, `abc.htm` link becomes visible. Now I want that when I enter `project` in the text field and press submit button `abc.htm` and `xyz.htm` and `cold.htm` links get visible. Same in case with writing under in the text field.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script Language="JavaScript">
    <!--
    function Blank_TextField_Validator() {
    // Check the value of the element named text_name from the form named text_form
    if (text_form.text_name.value == "") {
    // If null display and alert box
    alert("Please fill in the text field.");
    // Place the cursor on the field for revision
    text_form.text_name.focus();
    // return false to stop further processing
    return (false);
    }
    // If text_name is not null continue processing
   if (text_form.text_name.value == "project")
   document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block';
   else if (text_form.text_name.value == "under")
   document.getElementById('construction_link').style.display = 'block';
   else
   alert("Invalid keyword!");
   return (false);
   }
   -->
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <form name="text_form" method="get" action="#" 
    onsubmit="return Blank_TextField_Validator()">
    <a id='project_link' href='abc.htm' style='display: none;'>project</a>
     <a id='construction_link' href='New Text Document (3).htm' style='display:     none;'>construction</a>
     <input type="text" name="text_name" >
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
if (text_form.text_name.value == "project") 
    document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('project_link_1').style.display = 'block'; 

<form name="text_form" method="get" action="#" onsubmit="return Blank_TextField_Validator()">
    <a id='project_link' href='abc.htm' style='display: none;'>project</a> 
    <a id='project_link_1' href='xyz.htm' style='display: none;'>projects</a> 
    <a id='construction_link' href='New Text Document (3).htm' style='display: none;'>construction</a>
```

Comment: It seems you already know how to do that: `document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block';`. You just have to do that for every link you want to be visible.

Comment: but it just give me one link if i write project in the text fields i need 3 links how ll i do that?

Comment: Well, your HTML only contains one of the links, `<a id='project_link' href='abc.htm' style='display: none;'>project</a>`... either add the others to your HTML as well and use the same method or create them dynamically and add them to the DOM. Your question is not very clear, you just want to know how to "show" them. The line I quoted in my first comment does that.

Comment: Btw. I noticed that you basically built the code together form other questions. Believe, you won't get far with that method... either hire someone to do the work for you or start learning what you want to do. These questions are of no use to anyone but you which is not in the interest of this site (sorry).

Comment: i wan to do something like this: when i write project in the text field and press the submit button it should display 3 links first is abc.htm, second is xyz.htm and third is klo.htm. I wan to display multiple links when if (text_form.text_name.value == "project") statement is true.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But the code already contains all you need to know! You just have to multiply this logic. There are no special skills required to answer this question. Have a look at the code and think about it.

Comment: i am looking and i am trying but its not working, if you dont want to help then be quite and be polite. thankyou.

Comment: Then post what you have tried! I'm just trying to help you help yourself, by pointing you into the right direction :)

Comment: if (text_form.text_name.value == "project")
document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('project_link_1').style.display = 'block';
....
<form name="text_form" method="get" action="#" 
onsubmit="return Blank_TextField_Validator()">
<a id='project_link' href='abc.htm' style='display: none;'>project</a>
<a id='project_link_1' href='xyz.htm' style='display: none;'>projects</a>
<a id='construction_link' href='New Text Document (3).htm' style='display: none;'>construction</a>

Comment: Please add code to your question by editing it. Code in comments is impossible to read. You are close. If you have multiple statements inside an `if` clause you have to put them in a block (note the braces): `if(...) { .... } else if { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (text_form.text_name.value == "project") 
    document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('project_link_1').style.display = 'block';
```

to

```
if (text_form.text_name.value == "project") {
    document.getElementById('project_link').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('project_link_1').style.display = 'block'; 
}
```

Btw, I really agree with the commentators on the original question: you should learn JavaScript before posting questions about it. You will need to know what you are actually doing to succeed.